# Weird Android AsyncTask bug I can't understand

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, ksoap2

So I'm using an AsyncTask to perform a call to my windows WCF service. So far it has gone great, I can get it to call a method that returns a string and display it within the application. But when trying to methods that return a bool i get some errors..

Code

```
RegisterSeatTask task = new RegisterSeatTask();
task.execute(this);

protected class RegisterSeatTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(Context... arg0) {
try {
......
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());

if (!LicenseHandler.RegisterSeat(licenseKey, ident,android.os.Build.DEVICE,tm.getDeviceId())) {
                    return "License is invalid or does not have any empty seats!";
}
......
}
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public static boolean RegisterSeat(String License, String Identifier,
        String Device, String DeviceID) {
    try {

        METHOD_NAME = "RegisterSeat";
        SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService/RegisterSeat";

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("License", License);
        request.addProperty("MyIdentifier", Identifier);
        request.addProperty("Device", Device);
        request.addProperty("DeviceID", DeviceID);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        if (result.toString().toLowerCase() == "true") {
            return true;
        }
        // to get the data
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return false;
    }

}
```

However everytime i run the method RegisterSeat() the code stops and ends up on the last line inside the Catch() [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ERPe.png) and [e is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbfYL.png).. There are no expcetions cast?
[I can see the value of result.tostring()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5PFZ.png) it is either true or false as the wcf returns it. But somewhere everything bugs out and I don't know what to make of it :/!!

[image: like this]
[image: e is null]
[image: I can see the value of result.tostring()]

Comment: one thing I would note is that you should be using .equals("true") rather than "== true" to compare your strings

Comment: oh thats just wierd.. .equals did the trick... It now completed the method and returns the proper value.. Can you make an answer with this text so I can grant you the answer? :)

Comment: what is your eclipse version ? and what compiler level are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing I would note is that you should be using .equals("true") rather than "== true" to compare your strings

glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I think something is messed up in your setup. It's not possible that the program really reaches the breakpoint `return false` as it did in your screenshot, since `bugged` is `true`. Furthermore, in your second screenshot you're not yet in the `catch`, but on the `return false` in the inner part of the try. This statement will not throw an exception, so if you end up in the catch, it's very odd. My guess is that the deployed code and the code in your IDE is not identical. If I look at the code you pasted and the code you made a screenshot of, they aren't identical either. Fix this deployment problem, fix the point SnowyTracks mentioned in the comment and see what happens then.